# Distribute items into containers in twos - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I have a list of 10 items -- it is an array of hashes.

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'one'}, { id: 2, name: 'two' } .. { id: 10, name: 'ten' }]
```

I also have a random number of containers -- let's say 3, in this case. These containers are hashes with array values.

```
{ one: [], two: [], three: [] }
```

What I want to do, is iterate over the containers and drop 2 items at a time resulting in:

```
{ 
   one: [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:7}, {id:8}], 
   two: [{id:3}, {id:4}, {id:9}, {id:10}], 
   three: [{id:5}, {id:6}] 
}
```

Also, if the item list is an odd number (11), the last item is still dropped into the next container.

```
{ 
   one: [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:7}, {id:8}], 
   two: [{id:3}, {id:4}, {id:9}, {id:10}], 
   three: [{id:5}, {id:6}, {id:11}] 
}
```

*note: the hashes are snipped here so it's easier to read.*

My solution is something like this: (simplified)

```
x = 10
containers = { one: [], two: [], three: [] }

until x < 1 do
    containers.each do |c|
        c << 'x'
        c << 'x'
    end
    x -= 2
end

puts containers
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can achieve this but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you add which items you have in which format and what you want exactly ? currently your question is not understandable

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails].

Comment: @Amadan - I'm building this on rails, so any solution that can use rails specific features are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round-robin pair distribution into three bins:

```
bins = 3
array = 10.times.map { |i| i + 1 }
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

array.
  each_slice(2).                  # divide into pairs
  group_by.                       # group into bins
  with_index { |p, i| i % bins }. # round-robin style
  values.                         # get rid of bin indices
  each(&:flatten!)                # join pairs in each bin
```

Completely different approach, stuffing bins in order:

```
base_size, bins_with_extra = (array.size / 2).divmod(bins)
pos = 0
bins.times.map { |i|
  length = 2 * (base_size + (i < bins_with_extra ? 1 : 0)) # how much in this bin?
  array[pos, length].tap { pos += length }                 # extract and advance
}
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

If you absolutely need to have this in a hash,

```
Hash[%i(one two three).zip(binned_array)]
# => {:one=>[1, 2, 7, 8], :two=>[3, 4, 9, 10], :three=>[5, 6]}
```

The lovely (but likely not as performant) solution hinted at by Stefan Pochmann:

```
bins.times.with_object(array.to_enum).map { |i, e|
  Array.new(2 * (base_size + (i < bins_with_extra ? 1 : 0))) { e.next }
}
```

Comment: You could also `group_by.with_index` which avoids the indices, so you can just `each(&:flatten!)` the values.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan that's indeed simpler; I edited it in. #2 also looks more complex than it needs to be but can't figure it out :P

Comment: `array[pos ... pos += length]`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann nice :) but `tap`'s not what's bugging me; I hate having to initialise `pos` outside the `map`, and i don't like having to calculate length :P Oh well...

Comment: Ok then you won't like `e = array.to_enum` with `Array.new(length) { e.next }`, either :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Actually yes, I like that a lot :D I was actually trying with `iter = array.each` and `iter.take(n)` first, but that's not doing what I wanted (unlike what you wrote :D ). I guess I'm too much of a noob on Enumerators :) Also, I guess direct slicing should be faster than collecting from an enum one by one...

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show a different approach (and I would probably not use this one myself).

Given an array of items and the containers hash:

```
items = (1..10).to_a
containers = { one: [], two: [], three: [] }
```

You could [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) the array (in order not to modify the original one) and build an enumerator that [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle)s [`each_value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) in the hash:

```
array = items.dup
enum = containers.each_value.cycle
```

Using the above, you can [`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) 2 items off the array and [`push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-push) them to the [`next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) container [`until`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop) the array is [`emtpy?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F):

```
enum.next.push(*array.shift(2)) until array.empty?
```

Result:

```
containers
#=> {:one=>[1, 2, 7, 8], :two=>[3, 4, 9, 10], :three=>[5, 6]}
```

Comment: Plenty of approaches! \o/

Comment: Another variation: `items.each_slice(2).zip(containers.each_value.cycle) { |s, c| c.push(*s) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable#each_slice` to iterate over a range from `0` to `10` in 3s and then append to an array of arrays:

```
containers = [
  [],
  [],
  []
]

(1...10).each_slice(3) do |slice|
  containers[0] << slice[0]
  containers[1] << slice[1]
  containers[2] << slice[2]
end

p containers
# [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```